# How do I get a device's parent in c++ on windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I have found `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` to get properties from devices, but I havent figured out how to get the parent property (you can see this property when you open a devices properties in device manager, click on details, and choose parent from the property drop down. How do I access that property from native c++ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it by using: `CM_Get_Parent` found this reference thanks to Hans though, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The predefined DEVPKEY_Device_Parent guid is the key for the Parent property.  Read it with SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceProperty().

Comment: is there any way to get it in windows xp?